# Why SAX xml parser taking long time

Tags: perl

I have an application which is using SAX xml parser but observed that its talking long time ( ~30 sec) to parse xml file( xml file size of 5MB)

Is there solution/work around to improve the performance ?

Please find respective piece of code which causing the delay.

```
package XML::SAX::PurePerl;

sub _parse_systemid {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($uri) = @_;
    my $reader = XML::SAX::PurePerl::Reader::URI->new($uri);

   return $self->_parse($reader);  # taking 30 sec
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the BUGS section for the [module](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-SAX-0.99/SAX/PurePerl.pm);

> XML::SAX::PurePerl is slow. Very slow. I suggest you use something
>   else in fact.

Is there a reason why your are using the pureperl version? Are you able to install [XML::SAX](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-SAX-0.99/SAX.pm)?

I've also found [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) to be a solid xml workhorse; with options to load xml into hashes, and SAX2 support.

Comment: It is legacy code and already in use. Now i am looking into performance improvement.

Comment: Hi Harvey, Can you please let me know whether i can replace SAX with SAX2.0 APIs ?